# php select do something for each result

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a select list in witch the selected option is equal to the group element containing that list.

This is my code:

```
echo '<select title="Show Article in Group" id="edt-select-art">';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups");

$groups = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($groups, $row['0']);

    foreach($groups as $group) 
        { 
            if($gID == $group)
                {
                    echo '<option agid="'.$row['0'].'" selected>'.$row['2'].'</option>';
                }
            else
                {
                    echo '<option agid="'.$row['0'].'">'.$row['2'].'</option>';
                }
        }       

}
echo '</select>';
```

If I put the foreach outside the while, I can't get the `row[]` data, but if I put it inside, it doubles or triples the values.
Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You're pushing the row onto your array $groups. Then you're stepping through that same array and processing it. So of course you're getting duplicates - the first entry will be repeated every time. Also, your `<select>` doesn't have a `name` attribute, which may cause issues.

Comment: I wanted the array to contain the ids. if I print it, it looks ok.

Comment: Why are you using $groups at all? Why not just use the data directly in $rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing row[0], push row into groups and then Iterate over groups array like below :

```
echo '<select title="Show Article in Group" id="edt-select-art">';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups");

$groups = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($groups, $row);


}
 foreach($groups as $group) 
        { 
            if($gID == $group[0])
                {
                    echo '<option agid="'.$group['0'].'" selected>'.$group['2'].'</option>';
                }
            else
                {
                    echo '<option agid="'.$group['0'].'">'.$group['2'].'</option>';
                }
        }       

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I now realize how stupid my question was. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$groups` array.

```
echo '<select title="Show Article in Group" id="edt-select-art">';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option agid="'.$row['0'].'" '.($row['0'] == $gId ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$row['2'].'</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';
```